# Syntax of SPARQL query in Python to query ttl file

Tags: python, sparql, ttl, rdflib

I am trying to query a (originally .ttl) file with the RDFLib in Python. An extract from the file is shown below.

> http://id.vlaanderen.be/statistieken/dq/kubus-kadaster/observatie/0/0/0#id a qb:Observation ;
>       qb:dataSet http://id.vlaanderen.be/statistieken/dq/kubus-kadaster#id ;
>       statsvl:refArea http://id.fedstats.be/nis/11001#id ;
>       statsvl:timePeriod http://id.vlaanderen.be/statistieken/concept/jaar_1997#id ;
>       statsvl:oppervlaktetype http://id.vlaanderen.be/statistieken/concept/appartementen#id ;
>       sdmx-attribute:unitMeasure unit:Euro ;
>       qb:measureType statsvl:totaleki ;
>       statsvl:totaleki "916371"^^xsd:int .

I want to extract the value of **totaleki** for this example. I am using the [SPARQLWrapper](https://rdflib.github.io/sparqlwrapper/) to do this. However, I think there is something wrong with the WHERE clause. Does anyone know how I can get this value for this specific refArea?

```
import rdflib
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON

g = rdflib.Graph()
result = g.parse('cube7.ttl', format='n3')

sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://dbpedia.org/sparql")
sparql.setQuery("""
PREFIX statsvl: <http://id.vlaanderen.be/statistieken/def#>
SELECT ?refArea ?totaleki
WHERE { <http://id.fedstats.be/nis/11001#id> statsvl:refArea ?refArea 
        statsvl:totaleki ?totaleki}
""")
```

This produces the error: **QueryBadFormed: a bad request has been sent to the endpoint, probably the sparql query is bad formed.**

Answer (score 1):

Semicolon is missing after the first triple pattern:

```sql
PREFIX statsvl: <http://id.vlaanderen.be/statistieken/def#>
SELECT ?refArea ?totaleki
WHERE { <http://id.fedstats.be/nis/11001#id> statsvl:refArea ?refArea ;
                                             statsvl:totaleki ?totaleki .
}
```